# sublime text syntax definition

Tags: regex, text, sublimetext2, definition

I'm trying to make new syntax for sublime text.
Across docs highlight based on rules, here is the quote:

> Each rule consumes the matched text region, which will therefore be excluded from the next rule’s matching attempt (save for a few exceptions).

I have next file which i'm trying to highlight:

```
div
  div
    div
```

I have next rules to match (for example):

```
{
  "name": "entity.name.tag.z",
  "match": "[A-z]+"
},
{
  "name": "entity.language.z",
  "match": "\\s*[A-z]+"
},
```

As assumed 1st rule must match all 3 div's, so 2nd rule doesn't match anything.

But only 1st 'div' matched, 2nd and 3rd are not matched.  If I remove 2nd rule then all 3 are correctly matched.

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but I would not recommend using `A-z`, because it includes these characters: `[\]^_\``. Use `A-Za-z` instead.

Comment: Thanks for info, non know that, it on all regex or only sublime?

Comment: It's a general property of character classes. When you create a range in a character class, it works on ASCII (or Unicode) code points. e.g. when you use `A-z` you will include all characters that have an ASCII code between `65` (`A`) and `122` (`z`), which includes the mentioned non-letter characters.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert, but here is my supposition:

When you have only the first rule, it does not match the three lines in one single match, it is three separate matches because your first rule does not include whitespaces.
To be clear, the match is not

```
[match1]div
          div
             div[/match1]
```

but

```
[match1]div[/match1]
       [match1]div[/match1]
              [match1]div[/match1]
```

Once you added the second rule, it triggers at the beginning of the second line, **thus before the first rule**, and the result I expect is

```
[match1]div[/match1]
[match2]    div[/match2]
[match2]         div[/match2]
```